# Sql Server 2008, modify query via stored procedure into .NET ArrayList

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, arraylist

Below is an example of using the stored procedure(GetTimesWithCustomerNames) then via ArrayList collecting data retrieved by the query:

```
/*
    GetTimesWithCustomerNames 3571, 6, 2012, 1
    GetTimesWithCustomerNames '3571', '6', '2012', '0'

*/
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTimesWithCustomerNames]
@userid int=0, @month int=0, @year int=0,@reasonid int=0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if @userid!=0 begin

        create table #tmp (tId int, UserId int, 
        TimeIn1 smalldatetime, [TimeOut1] smalldatetime, 
        TimeIn2 smalldatetime, [TimeOut2] smalldatetime, tId2 int,
        TimeIn3 smalldatetime, [TimeOut3] smalldatetime, tId3 int,
        ActiveDate smalldatetime, ReasonID int, Name nvarchar(100), ReasonType nvarchar(100),
        TotalMins int)

        insert into #tmp (tId, UserId, TimeIn1, TimeOut1, ActiveDate, ReasonID, Name, ReasonType)
        SELECT
        t1.tId, t1.UserId, t1.TimeIn, t1.[TimeOut], t1.ActiveDate, t1.ReasonID, tblCustomers.Name,
        (select reasontype from tblTimeReas where ReasonID=t1.ReasonID) as ReasonType
        FROM tblTime t1
        inner join tblCustomers on t1.UserId=tblCustomers.custID
        where (t1.userid=@userid)
        and (DATEPART(MONTH,t1.timein)=@month or @month=0)
        and (DATEPART(YEAR,t1.timein)=@year or @year=0)
        and (t1.reasonid = @reasonid or @reasonid=0)        
        and
        (select COUNT(1) from tblTime t2 where userid=@userid and datediff(day,t2.TimeIn,t1.TimeIn)=0 and t2.tId<t1.tId)=0

        update #tmp
        set tId2 = (select top 1 tId from tblTime t2 where userid=@userid and DATEDIFF(day,t2.timein,#tmp.timein1)=0
                        and t2.tId>#tmp.tId order by tId asc)
        update #tmp
        set tId3 = (select top 1 tId from tblTime t3 where userid=@userid and DATEDIFF(day,t3.timein,#tmp.timein2)=0
                        and t3.tId>#tmp.tId2 order by tId asc)

        update #tmp
        set TimeIn2 = (select TimeIn from tblTime where tId=tId2),
            TimeOut2 = (select [TimeOut] from tblTime where tId=tId2),
            TimeIn3 = (select TimeIn from tblTime where tId=tId3),
            TimeOut3 = (select [TimeOut] from tblTime where tId=tId3)

        update #tmp set TotalMins = (
            isnull(DATEDIFF(minute,timein1,timeout1),0)+
            isnull(DATEDIFF(minute,timein2,timeout2),0)+
            isnull(DATEDIFF(minute,timein3,timeout3),0)
        )

        select * from #tmp order by TimeIn1
        drop table #tmp

    end

END
```

I would like to know, for given userid I can have all data returned into an ArrayList - what is the way to retrive a set of values per userid ? Will it be possible to have a data returned per user(few) in an arrayList and **not for one only** like this procedure ?

In this query data is `TimeIn` `TimeOut` `ActiveDate` etc...

- ReEditing
  I think my question is should the task be for the code behind in a foreach loop or would it be possible to modify the procedure to accept more than one userid?

The code I am using to store data in code behind is:

```
 public static ArrayList loadData(string sql)
    {

        DBManager dbManager = new DBManager(DataProvider.SqlServer, "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=databaseName;Integrated Security=True");

        ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

        try
        {
            dbManager.Open();
            dbManager.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandType.Text, sql);
            while (dbManager.DataReader.Read())
            {
               Hashtable x = new Hashtable();

                for (int i = 0; i < dbManager.DataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    x.Add(dbManager.DataReader.GetName(i), dbManager.DataReader.GetValue(i));
                }
                x.Add("COUNTER", data.Count+1);
                data.Add(x);
            }
        }
        catch { data = null; }
        finally
        {
            dbManager.Dispose();
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Why would you use `ArrayList`? Are you using .NET 1.1 or below?

Comment: @JohnSaunders no not at all (4.0). it's a code i am reusing . the new task is to get more then one userid set of data then populating a table via each users data what is the proper way?

Comment: Suddenly I thought I was back in time like 10 years ago :). Sorry I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Do a favor for your successors: fix that obsolete code while you're in there. Use `Dictionary<string,object>` instead of `HashTable`, and `List<Dictionary<string,object>>` instead of `ArrayList`. Also, put `dbManager` in a `using` block, and remove the `try/catch` entirely.

Comment: @JohnSaunders , thanks a lot for your comments, dealing with task involving database usually led me to using grid view instead , this code is used with rendering the table<html> controls dynamically , so as i am new (to digging out through the walls of .net ready-made object such as grid view ) and instead using the old fashion methods ,i really could use a simple example-code using `Dictionary<string,object>` `List<Dictionary<string,object>>` instead , as you suggest ,just so i would understand the form or structure of the basic idea thanks again

Comment: The behavior is identical. Just change the types to those I mentioned and your code should "just work".

Comment: @JohnSaunders your last Comment was not in the viewable list it was hidden so i didn't see it till now, gonna give it a try . these types are less error prone or better performs or more flexible to work with, i am asking actually why mainly you prefer it over the ancient `ArrayList` & `HashTable`

Comment: @LoneXcoder: all of the above. Besides, why use flint knives when you could use steel knives?

Comment: @Jhon Saunders, that was 3 weeks ago , i already implemented the use of list<Dictionary> And Dictionary<string,object> close to this conversation date didn't have the time to correct it here , now i am posting my new version and remembring your " should just work" was really easy to implement /refactor my code , as im still far from really getting totally what's behind the screen of old vs new methods i've used it hope to learn about what was gained , just for the sake of knowing for instance what is technologically more advanced in this new "decade" with dot.net as an example. thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> loadData(string sql)
    {

    itson = (sql.StartsWith("GetTimesWith"));
    DBManager dbManager = new DBManager(DataProvider.SqlServer, "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=hental;Integrated Security=True");

    //ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> data = new List<Dictionary<string,object>>();
    try
    {
        dbManager.Open();
        dbManager.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandType.Text, sql);
        while (dbManager.DataReader.Read())
        {
           //Hashtable x = new Hashtable();
           Dictionary<string, object> x = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            for (int i = 0; i < dbManager.DataReader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                x.Add(dbManager.DataReader.GetName(i), dbManager.DataReader.GetValue(i));
            }

            x.Add("COUNTER", data.Count+1);
            data.Add(x);
            ncx = data.Count;

        }
    }
    catch { data = null; }
    finally
    {
        dbManager.Dispose();
    }

    return data;
}
```